# How to approach multivariable integration problems?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

I have a problem that seems to be a cylindrical conversion problem, but I could not find bounds for r.

The problem asked me to find the volume bounded by $z = (2x)^2 + y^2$ and $z+y^2 = 2$.

I first drew the graph

[image: The oval has a shape like this, disappears if z = 0]

The oval has a shape like this, disappears if z = 0
[image: The surface curved like this along z-y continuous inf for all x]

The surface curved like this along z-y continuous inf for all x

So I choose cylindrical conversion $x = r\cos\theta, y =r\sin\theta, z = z$
bounds are $0<z<2, 0<\theta<2\pi$, but what is r? I think it is changing from $\sqrt{z}/2$ to $\sqrt{z}$ governed by $\theta$.

I know I want to setup something like $\iiint dzrdrd\theta$ but I am not sure what do I put in there, just an empty integral?

Comment: Yes, so what is the intersection of the two surfaces and what is its projection in the $xy$-plane? What are the $z$ limits for fixed $r,\theta$?

Comment: I equated the two equations and got 2x^2+y^2 = 1. But I do not know how to find constant r. always end up with some equation in terms of $\theta$ for r.

Comment: Is it really $4x^2$ and not $2x^2$?

Comment: yes, it is 4x^2, I do not know whether I should be using cylindrical conversion if the shape is an oval. Seems like no circular symmetry is a problem. Is it possible to solve this using just x and y? The integral seems like a nightmare.

Comment: Have you learned only cylindrical and spherical coordinates, or do you know about more general change of variables procedures?

Comment: OK. I assume not. I recommend trying cartesian coordinates, specifically in the order $dx\,dz\,dy$.